# Can't load '/Compress/Raw/Zlib/Zlib.so'

Tags: perl

I am trying to run Variant effect predictor perl script (by ensembl) and I am getting this error:

```
Testing VEP script
ERROR: Testing VEP script failed with the following error
Can't load '/home/sahel/perl5/lib/perl5/x86_64-linux/auto/Compress/Raw/Zlib/Zlib.so' for module Compress::Raw::Zlib: /home/sahel/perl5/lib/perl5/x86_64-linux/auto/Compress/Raw/Zlib/Zlib.so: undefined symbol: PL_unitcheckav at /usr/lib64/perl5/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/DynaLoader.pm line 230.
 at /home/sahel/perl5/lib/perl5/Compress/Zlib.pm line 11
Compilation failed in require at /home/sahel/perl5/lib/perl5/Compress/Zlib.pm line 11.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /home/sahel/perl5/lib/perl5/Compress/Zlib.pm line 11.
Compilation failed in require at /projects/sahel_proj/localperl/Bio/EnsEMBL/Variation/ProteinFunctionPredictionMatrix.pm line 73.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /projects/sahel_proj/localperl/Bio/EnsEMBL/Variation/ProteinFunctionPredictionMatrix.pm line 73.
Compilation failed in require at /projects/sahel_proj/localperl/Bio/EnsEMBL/Variation/TranscriptVariationAllele.pm line 65.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /projects/sahel_proj/localperl/Bio/EnsEMBL/Variation/TranscriptVariationAllele.pm line 65.
Compilation failed in require at /projects/sahel_proj/localperl/Bio/EnsEMBL/Variation/TranscriptVariation.pm line 57.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /projects/sahel_proj/localperl/Bio/EnsEMBL/Variation/TranscriptVariation.pm line 57.
Compilation failed in require at /projects/sahel_proj/localperl/Bio/EnsEMBL/Variation/DBSQL/TranscriptVariationAdaptor.pm line 68.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /projects/sahel_proj/localperl/Bio/EnsEMBL/Variation/DBSQL/TranscriptVariationAdaptor.pm line 68.
Compilation failed in require at /projects/sahel_proj/localperl/Bio/EnsEMBL/Variation/VariationFeature.pm line 105.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /projects/sahel_proj/localperl/Bio/EnsEMBL/Variation/VariationFeature.pm line 105.
Compilation failed in require at /projects/sahel_proj/localperl/Bio/EnsEMBL/Variation/Utils/VEP.pm line 52.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /projects/sahel_proj/localperl/Bio/EnsEMBL/Variation/Utils/VEP.pm line 52.
Compilation failed in require at variant_effect_predictor.pl line 57.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at variant_effect_predictor.pl line 57.
```

I have installed all required modules by cpan and set the path to the modules by:

```
echo 'eval `/projects/sahel_proj/localperl/bin/perl -I ~/perl5/lib/perl5 -Mlocal::lib`' >> ~/.profile
```

Compress::Raw::Zlib and Compress::Zlib seem to be successfully installed:

```
./bin/perl -e 'use Compress::Raw::Zlib;'
./bin/perl -e 'use Compress::Zlib;'
```

So I can not think of what could be wrong and could not find any thing online...

This my first experience working with perl ever :( , any help would be appreciated...

Thank you so much

Comment: Which version of `Compress::Raw::Zlib` are you using ? How did you install ?

Comment: reinstall Compress::Raw::Zlib

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seems to be a Perl version mismatch. The signs point to: The `.so` you are loading was built using one version of Perl and it's being loaded by an incompatible version of Perl.

I suspect your testing is done with one `perl` (the one used to install the modules), while the actual program is being run with the another `perl`.

Now you know why I can't fathom why people think `INSTALL_BASE` aka `--install_base` is a good idea. Sure, the directory structure is prettier, but it causes these problems! You're using `INSTALL_BASE` aka `--install_base` (a way to tell `Makefile.PL` and `Build.PL` where to install modules) via local::lib.

Solution 1.

Run your script using the same `perl` that you used to install the modules.

Solution 2.

Get rid of the directory in which local::lib installed your modules and reinstall them without using local::lib:

```
perl Makefile.PL PREFIX=~ LIB=~/lib/perl5
make
make test
make install
```

or

```
perl Build.PL --prefix ~ --lib ~/lib/perl5
./Build
./Build test
./Build install
```

If you do the above using both `perl`, version-specific modules will be available to both `perl`. If you do the above using only one `perl`, version-specific modules will only be available to that `perl`. No conflicts.

(You can use `cpan` by configuring it to use the above commands.)

Don't forget to tell `perl` where to locate your modules. In your login script,

```
export PERL5LIB=~/lib/perl5
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help... It is fixed now. :)

Comment: but I have another problem, when I try to run the script I get this error message: Downloading required files
 - fetching ensembl
** GET http://cvs.sanger.ac.uk/cgi-bin/viewvc.cgi/ensembl.tar.gz?root=ensembl&view=tar&only_with_tag=branch-ensembl-66 ==> Can't locate object method "flush" via package "IO::Handle" at /home/sahel_proj/lib/perl5/LWP/UserAgent.pm line 535, <> line 1.
but both modules that perls refer to are already installed successfully... and I used the same version of perl all the time... Thank you so much again for your help :)

Comment: I sure hope it's installed since it's part of Perl. The real questio is whether the module loaded? (`use IO::Handle;`)

Comment: (Note that Perl 5.14 -- or is it upcoming 5.16? -- loads IO::File and thus IO::Handle automatically in some circumstances)

Comment: That was it. Thanks.... once I added "use IO::Handle;" to the script, everything started working perfectly... Thank you so much for all your help :)